# Dictionary of Words in SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We introduced **SonarQube** into our project which is working fine, but we have names like **SelfAHFController**. For Sonar, the name **SelfAHFController** should be **SelfAhfController**.

In StyleCop was possible to create a dictionary of allowed words. We would like to have **AHF** in this dictonary, but also to keep the CammelCase rule. It means, for words found in the dictionary, Sonar should igore the CammelCase rule.

Where can I specify this in Sonar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We still do not support custom dictionaries for the naming rules. We have an [open ticket](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/320), but I cannot promise a specific date when it will be developed.